# Stopping VirtualTopic to forward message on its consumer queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Is there a way to stop a VirtualTopic from forwarding message to its consumer queues on the fly. May be using jconsole or from producer side commands or from consumer on that queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the queue to stop messages to it (obviously). That can be made from jconsole or similar. However, if your consumer has admin rights (by default this is the case, connecting to 61616), the queue will be recreated as long as the consumer continues to read.

If you want to be in control, maybe you should not allow admin rights for the consumer and create the queue manually in webconsole or jconsole.

There is no simple "pause subscription" command, which I guess you are looking for.